# Doxygen looking for third party headers referenced in namespace

Tags: c++, doxygen

Doxygen is generating errors because it can't find a header in a third party library. If I include the path to the header in the doxyfile, it then complains it can't find windows.h and other such headers. I don't want doxygen to reference those headers.

Doxygen only does this when I include the third party header in a namespace. If I remove the namespace doxygen doesn't complain.

The error I get is

```
warning: include file msipc.h not found, perhaps you forgot to add its directory to INCLUDE_PATH?
```

Comment: Including a third-party header within a namespace is asking for trouble when you actually link the program (never mind Doxygen)...

Comment: Not for what I'm doing. There's nothing to link from third party library. Just need it for the types, enums and such. I'm using LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to call functions.